# How to enable enterprise application for users authenticated by external Identity provider in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement Azure B2C to provide authentication to users from multiple sources. I have internal organisation users - which are authenticated by connecting the organisation's AD as an external identity provider - and external users - which are invited to the B2C tenancy. I have created an enterprise application to centralise authentication for other infrastructure. The application is accessible to all users in the tenancy (not restricted to select users by adding them) through SSO set up in the application.

The issue I am having is providing access to the enterprise application to users that are authenticated by the external IdP (i.e. internal organisation users). I don't want to have to create a user in the B2C tenancy for every user that authenticates via the external IdP (unless there is an automated way to do this?). The image below shows the message a user sees when trying to sign in.

[image: Azure Authentication error message]

**How do I configure the App/B2C tenancy so that users authenticated by an external identity provider can then access the enterprise application?**

I have seen that you can make an app multitenant in the app registration settings which I have tried with no luck. This approach gets caught with the application ID URI. The enterprise app has an Identity (Entity ID) which does not conform to the requirement of the application ID URI for multitenant applications (i.e. https://.onmicrosoft.com/).

Any help with this issue will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to sign-in from only **Single Azure AD Organization**, then check the below:

Create an **Azure AD application in the AAD tenant** and include the following redirect URI: `https://your-B2C-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-B2C-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`

[image]

Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider) and add **Azure AD as the Identity Provider** like below:

[image]

Create a **B2C user flow** for Azure AD, choose an identity provider, and save the flow as shown below:

[image]

Now, Run the user flow:

[image]

To login in with an AAD user account, choose **Azure AD**:

[image]

*The user got signed in successfully like below:*

[image]

**The above user is added as the Member** like below:

[image]

If you want users to sign-in from only **Multi-Tenant Azure AD Organization**, then refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).